# Decomposition of 1-forms in simply connected open subset of Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

Let $U$ be a simply connected bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $\Omega^k$ be the space of $k$-forms on $U$, and let $d_k: \Omega^k \to \Omega^{k+1}$ be the exterior derivative. Endow $U$ with a Riemannian metric and let $\delta_k: \Omega^k \to \Omega^{k-1}$ be the corresponding co-differential operator.

A 1-form $\omega \in \Omega^1$ is

- *closed* if $d_1{\omega} = 0 \in \Omega^2$, i.e. $\omega \in \ker{d_1}$
- *exact* if $\omega = d_0f$ for some $f \in \Omega^0$, i.e. $\omega \in \text{im}~{d_0}$
- *co-closed* if $\delta_1{\omega} = 0 \in \Omega^0$, i.e. $\omega \in \ker{\delta_1}$
- *co-exact* if $\omega = \delta_2{\beta}$ for some $\beta \in \Omega^2$, i.e. $\omega \in \text{im}~{\delta_2}$

Since $U$ is simply connected, by Poincaré lemma any 1-form is

- closed iff exact, and
- co-closed iff co-exact

**Question**: is it true that $\Omega^1$ admits the orthogonal direct sum decomposition
$$\Omega^1 = \text{im}~{d_0} \oplus \text{im}~{\delta_2}$$

I think the answer is "no". **If $\Omega^1$ was a finite dimensional vector space**, then

$$
\begin{split}
\Omega^{1} & = \ker{d_{1}} \oplus \left( \ker{d_{1}}  \right)^{\perp} \\
& = \ker{d_{1}} \oplus \text{im}~{\delta_{2}} \\
& = \text{im}~{d_{0}} \oplus \text{im}~{\delta_{2}} \\
\end{split}
$$
where

- the first equality is true by definition of direct sum and orthogonal complement, since $\ker{d_1}$ is a linear subspace;
- the second equality is true since $\delta_2$ is the adjoint of $d_1$;
- the last equality holds by Poincarè lemma.

But, $\Omega^1$ is a module over the algebra of smooth functions $C^{\infty}(U)$, so the above does not make sense - right?

## Edit

Here is the proof that Hodge theorem holds true for a special Riemannian metric on the relative interior of the standard simplex.

$\newcommand{\rint}[1]{\mathring{#1}}$
$\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal{X}}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\d}{d}$
$\newcommand{\pull}[1]{#1^{*}}$
$\newcommand{\topspace}{\R^{n+1}_{>0}}$

**Prop**. There exists a Riemannian metric such that Hodge theorem holds true for the space of 1-forms on the relative interior of the standard simplex that are well-behaved on the boundary.

**Proof.**

Consider the relative interior of the standard $n$-dimensional simplex seen as an immersed submanifold of the positive orthant $\topspace$:

$$\rint{\X} = \{x \in \topspace: \sum_{i = 0}^n x_i = 1\} \hookrightarrow \topspace$$

Consider the standard Euclidean coordinates and endow $\topspace$ with the following Riemannian metric (known in the literature as *Shahshahani* metric [1, 2]):
$$g(x) = \sum_{i, j = 0}^n \frac{\delta_{ij}}{x_i} \, dx^i \otimes dx^j$$
The matrix representation of this metric is $g(x) = \text{diag}(x_0, \dots, x_n)$.

Considering the following diffeomorphism of $\topspace$ onto itself:
$$F: \topspace \to \topspace$$
$$F(x) = 2\sqrt{x}$$
$$F^{-1}(y) = \frac{y^2}{4}$$
This is known as *Akin transformation* [3].

The image of $\rint{\X}$ under $F$ is the portion of the sphere of radius $2$ lying in the positive orthant:
$$\rint{C}  := F(\rint{\X}) = \{y \in \topspace: \sum_{i = 0}^n y_i^2 = 4 \}$$
Furthermore it's easy to check that the pull-back of the metric $g$ along $F^{-1}$ is the Euclidean metric on $\topspace$. Hence, $F$ restricted to $\rint{\X}$ is an isometry $F|_{\rint{\X}}: \rint{\X} \to \rint{C}$ between $\rint{\X}$ that inherits the Shahshahani metric from the ambient space, and $\rint{C}$
that inherits the Euclidean metric from the ambient space.

Let now $V$ be a 1-form defined on a tubolar neighborhood $U$ of $\rint{\X}$ (in particular, well-behaved on the boundary of $\rint{\X}$), and let $v$ be the restriction of $V$ to $\rint{X}$. In Euclidean coordinates $V$ can be expressed as
$$V(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n V_i(x) \, dx^i$$
where $V_i$ are smooth functions on $U$. Let $\omega = (F^{-1})^*{V}$ be the pull-back of $v$ on $F(U)$. By an explicit computation
$$\omega(y) = \sum_{i = 0}^n y_i \, (V_i \circ F^{-1})(y) \, dy^i$$
Since both $F$ and the $V_i$-s are well-behaved on the boundary of $\rint{\X}$, the 1-form $\omega$ is well-behaved on the closure $C$ of $\rint{C}$.

Then, by the Extension Lemma for Smooth Functions [4, Lemma 2.26], there exists a 1-form $\tilde{\omega}$ defined on the whole sphere $S$ of radius $2$ that agrees with $\omega|_C$ on $C$ and that is zero outside an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $C$.

The sphere is a closed (compact, no boundary) oriented manifold that inherits the Euclidean metric from the ambient space; thus Hodge theorem applies to the $1$-form $\tilde{\omega}$:

$$\tilde{\omega} = d{f} + \delta{\beta} + \gamma$$
with $f$ smooth function on $S$, $\beta$ 2-form on $S$, and $\gamma$ harmonic 1-form on $S$. Notice that if $n \geq 2$ then $S$ is simply connected and the harmonic component vanishes identically.

The restriction to $\rint{C}$ gives

$$
\begin{split}
\tilde{\omega}|_{\rint{C}} = \omega|_{\rint{C}} & = \left( d\psi + \delta\beta + \gamma \right)|_{\rint{C}} \\
& = d{\left( \psi|_{\rint{C}} \right)} +  \delta{\left( \beta|_{\rint{C}} \right)} + \gamma|_{\rint{C}}
\end{split}
$$
Pulling $\omega|_{\rint{C}}$ back to $\rint{\X}$ gives

$$
v = \pull{F}{\omega|_{\rint{C}}} = \pull{F} \Big( \d{\left( \psi|_{\rint{C}} \right)} +  \delta{\left( \beta|_{\rint{C}} \right)} + \gamma|_{\rint{C}} \Big) 
$$

The exterior derivative always commutes with the pull-back, and the codifferential commutes with the pull-back via isometries, so

$$
v = \d\Big( \pull{F}(\psi|_{\rint{C}}) \Big) +  \delta\Big( \pull{F}(\beta|_{\rint{C}}) \Big) + \pull{F} \left( \gamma|_{\rint{C}} \right)
$$
where

- $\pull{F}(\psi|_{\rint{C}})$ is a smooth function on $\rint{\X}$
- $\pull{F}(\beta|_{\rint{C}})$ is a 2-form on $\rint{\X}$
- $\pull{F} \left( \gamma|_{\rint{C}} \right)$ is a harmonic 1-form on $\rint{\X}$

q.e.d.

---

1. Shahshahani, S. A new mathematical framework for the study of linkage and selection. (American Mathematical Soc., 1979).
2. Mertikopoulos, P. & Sandholm, W. H. Riemannian game dynamics. Journal of Economic Theory 177, 315–364 (2018).
3. Sandholm, W. H. Population games and evolutionary dynamics. (MIT press, 2010).
4. Lee, J. M. Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. (Springer-Verlag New York, 2012).

Comment: The key to your argument is that $V$ is well behaved at the boundary of the simplex. There are forms on $\mathcal{X}^0$ which do not extend to its boundary.

Answer (score 4):

The decomposition you're looking for is referred to as the Hodge decomposition, and for forms over a compact oriented Riemannian manifold one has $\Omega^k(M)=\mathrm{im} d_{k-1}\oplus \mathrm{im} \delta_{k+1}\oplus \mathcal{H}^k$ where $\mathcal{H}^k$ is the space of harmonic $k$-forms.

In the non-compact case things are somewhat more subtle, since even though $d_k$ and $\delta_{k+1}$ are formally adjoint, they need not truely be adjoint in a more meaningful (functional analytic) sense.

Consider $U=(-1,1)\times (-1,1)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. There is a diffeomorphism $\phi:U\to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $(x,y)\mapsto (\tan(\pi x/2, \tan(\pi y/2))$. Pulling back the standard Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ makes $\phi:U\to \mathbb{R}^2$ an orientation preserving isometry. The codifferential on $\Omega^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is $\delta=\star^{-1}d\star$, so if $\omega=fdx\wedge dy$ then $\delta\omega=\star^{-1}(\partial_x fdx+\partial_y f d_y)=\partial_xf dy-\partial_yfdx$. We have $d\delta\omega=(\partial_x^2f+\partial_y^2f)dx\wedge dy$, so if $f$ is chosen to be non-constant harmonic (i.e. the real part of an entire holomorphic function), $d\delta\omega=0$ and by the Poincare lemma, $\delta\omega=dg$ for some nonconstant $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$. This of course means that $\mathrm{im\delta}\cap \mathrm{im d}\neq 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since $U$ is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2$, one sees that $\delta\phi^*\omega=d\phi^*g$, so the statement need not be true for sets which are bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

As I have suggested, things are somewhat nicer in the compact case. Given $M$ a compact oriented Riemannian manifold without boundary, for $\omega\in \Omega^k(M)$ and $\alpha\in \Omega^{k+2}$ we have \begin{align}(d\omega,\delta\alpha)&=\int_Md\omega\wedge d\star\alpha\\
&=\int_M d(\omega\wedge d\star\alpha)-(-1)^{n-k-1}\omega\wedge dd\star \alpha\\
&=\int_M d(\omega\wedge d\star\alpha)\\
&=0\end{align}
The final equality coming from Stokes' theorem. This means that $\mathrm{im}d_{k-1}$ is perpendicular to $\mathrm{im}\delta_{k+1}$ with respect to the inner product structure on $\Omega^k(M)$ induced by the metric. If the manifold has $H^1(M,\mathbb{R})=0$, the Hodge decomposition and DeRham's theorem tell us that $\Omega^1(M)=\mathrm{im} d_{k-1}\oplus \mathrm{im}\delta_{k+1}$.

EDIT: One has $\star^2\sigma=(-1)^{n(n-k)}\sigma$ so $\star^{-1}=\pm\star$, when restricted to $\Omega^k$ for fixed $k$, consistent with the convention.

Comment: Of course the OP's interest is in the non-compact case. You're pointing out that the exact and coexact forms certainly may not be direct summands. When we don't have compact support, or even $L^2$, then there must be a counterexample to the (not direct) sum question?

Comment: Thanks J.V.Gaiter; I know (superficially) Hodge theorem in the compact case, and as @TedShifrin points out I am interested in the simply-connected, non-compact case.

In particular I am working on the relative interior of the standard simplex, that is an open convex subset of the Euclidean space. I managed to show that, for a special class of metrics and this special space, it is indeed true that every 1-form decomposes uniquely as $df + \delta\beta$, and I was wondering if this holds in more generality.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter why do you define $\delta = \star^{-1}d\star$? I saw it defined everywhere (up to a sign) as $\delta = \star d \star$

Comment: I edited the question to specify that $U$ shall be also bounded.

Comment: @DavideL I have edit my answer to reflect your comments. You should post your proof for the restricted case as they may give hints for under what expanded assumptions the claim may or may not hold.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter thanks for the edit about the bounded case, it's very helpful. I added my proof for the restricted case. I use a special metric known as Shahshahani metric (that is an instance of the class of metrics I'm working with), with the special property of mapping isometrically the simplex to the portion of the sphere in the positive orthant endowed with the Euclidean metric.

Comment: The idea is to pull-back a 1-form from the simplex to the portion of the sphere, extend the form to the whole sphere, perform Hodge the decomposition (since the sphere is compact), and pull-back the decomposition to the simplex.